# How big would hammers have to be for an insect-sized humanoid to use?

Tags: humanoid, tools, size

This humanoid is roughly the same mass as a housefly, and has similar strength in its limbs. They have formed a society, and can create complex tools. One of these tools is a hammer used to drive nails, like a real claw-hammer (though it has no claw). What size/shape would such a hammer need to be to drive nails?

Comment: Am I missing something? If your humanoid is 1% the size of the average human then why wouldn't the hammer be the same shape and 1% the size? What is factually different that wouldn't simply scale?

Comment: The nail would weight more than the fly unless the nail is not a standard tiny brad. The force required to drive a nail in a press is about 250kg. I don't see how a fly sized person is going to generate this force with a hammer the size of a human hair.

Comment: How big are the nails and what are they made of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more interesting concept than it sounds. As some commenters are already pointing out, mass scales. Just scale the hammer and nails down to the humanoids's scale and you're done, right? Not so much.

Materials don't scale like that. If you scale a hammer and nails (even rather large spikes) to the humanoid's scale, the humanoid wouldn't be able to use those nails very effectively in most materials. Wood, like many materials we're accustomed to, is made up of small fibers. Nails work at human scale because the fibers are small enough that the wood behaves more or less like a homogenous material. At the humanoid's scale, it'd be more like trying to hold a bundle of wicker to another bundle of wicker with a normal nail. It'd sort of work but not very effectively. A hammer and nails might be a good choice for things that are homogenous at that scale, such as most plastics, but even then nails aren't as effective as rivets, glues, etc.

So the answer to your question is that the hammer would have to be proportionally much larger than the humanoid's scale, and so would the nails, in order to have them close enough to human scale that they can be effective. Picture a small finishing nail, and a team of the mini humanoids operating something like a heavy battering ram to drive it in.

The answer to the question you didn't ask is that this method would not be the humanoids' first choice for fastening things and they're likely stick to things that work well at their scale. Glues and cements work quite well, as do rope (thread?) lashings, and even bolts and rivets after a hole has been drilled, though they'd need heads wider than at human scale to account for the different material properties at that scale.

Comment: one humanoid could operate one battering ram just fine, thanks to the square-cube law

Comment: @Firestryke I don't see how that applies here. A normal-scale human can't operate such a ram alone. Such rams were typically carried by a team of soldiers, or mounted on a structure that allowed it to swing forward. I don't see how the Square Cube Law applies.

Comment: Because these humanoids are the size of a fly, its like ants. But with human muscles, if a human were scaled down to that size they would be superhuman.

Comment: @Firestryke Firstly, no. Smaller/fewer muscle cells wouldn't translate to greater strength, and ants aren't strong because of their scale but because of their physiology. Secondly, OP clearly stated that the micro-humanoids have "similar strength in their limbs". I assumed this meant similar in proportion to a human but it COULD mean to a fly, and even then a single fly would be unable to lift and heave a ram a hundred times their mass.

Comment: Ants. They lift ten times their own weight and they have very little muscle mass. Square. Cube. Law.

Comment: A humanoid the size of an ant with the proportional muscle mass of the average man would allow him to lift even more than just ten times their own weight

Comment: @Firestryke The Square Cube Law has nothing to do with the different biologies of insects and mammals. By your logic, elephants should be significantly weaker than humans and mice should be much stronger. They aren't. Please read up on insect biology and understand why most creatures with exoskeletons are proportionally stronger than those with endoskeletons.